# How to switch on the preview in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

My overleaf-site do not show the preview anymore. I have the source code and the bar for the project files (which can be toggled on and of by clicking on <kbd>PROJECT</kbd> in the top bar. The top bar has further more only <kbd>VERSIONS</kbd>, <kbd>PDF</kbd> and <kbd>SHARE</kbd> but no button for the preview). How can I switch on (I do not mean to switch between auto and manually refreshing) the preview?

[image: This is a screenshot from my project]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the left pointing triangle in the top right, just below your username.

[image]

Comment: My computer didn't show the arrow. But clicking on the space, where it should be, solved the Problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Qaswed Strange, but probably a browser issue. Did you try other browsers?

Comment: or try Ctrl+Shift+R to reload the page?

Comment: My working PC only allows to use one specific browser. Reloading the page didn't help. But now, as I'm able to work again, I'm fine with it :)